# advice on appropriate database for click logging reporting

Tags: database, architecture, amazon-simpledb, amazon-dynamodb

I am about to build a service that logs clicks and transactions from an e-commerce website. I expect to log millions of clicks every month.

I will use this to run reports to evaluate marketing efforts and site usage (similar to Google Analytics*). I need to be able to make queries, such as best selling product, most clicked category, average margin, etc.

*As some actions occur at later times and offline GA doesn´t fullfill all our needs.

The reporting system will not have a heady load and it will only be used internally.

My plan is to place loggable actions in a que and have a separate system store these to a database.

My question is what database I should use for this. Due to corporate IT-policy I do only have these options; SimpleDB (AWS), DynamoDB (AWS) or MS SQL/My SQL

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Fredrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked this excelent Amazon documentation page ? http://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/ It helps to pick the best database from their products.

From my experience, I would advise that you do **not use DynamoDB for this purpose**. There is no real `select` equivalent and you will have hard time  modeling your data. It is feasible, but not trivial.

On the other hand, **SimpleDB provides a `select` operation** that would considerably simplify the model. Nonetheless, it is advised against volumes > 10GB: http://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/

For the last resort option, RDS, I think you can do pretty much everything with it.

Comment: thanks for your input. I will start prototyping uing simpleDB. I can always use different domains to get around the 10GB limit.